Row colours disappear when breaking up my table in two when working with MANIM
I'm trying to color values according to groups in a table. This works so far, but I want to break my table and only show head and tail, but somehow my coloring goes wrong for the end of the head and the end of the tail... Also the coloring of the groups goes wrong at the end. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I'm rather new to MANIM, so any help is appreciated!
from manim import *
import random  # Import de random module

class DataToHistogram(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        # Step 1: Generate data for 40 respondents
        data = []
        for i in range(1, 41):  # 40 respondents
            group = "Mindfulness" if random.random() > 0.5 else "Wandelaar"
            base_score = random.randint(40, 70)  # Base score
            score = base_score + 10 if group == "Wandelaar" else base_score  # Higher score for Wanderers
            data.append([str(i), group, str(score)])  # Append Respondentnummer, Group, and Score

        # Step 2: Create a table with generated data
        table = Table(
            data,
            col_labels=[
                Text("Respondentnummer", font_size=20, color="#FFD700"),  # Light yellow
                Text("Groep", font_size=20, color="#FFD700"),
                Text("Kwaliteit van Leven", font_size=20, color="#FFD700")
            ],
            include_outer_lines=True,
            line_config={"color": "#888888"}  # Softer gray for table lines
        )

        # Scale and position the table
        table.scale(0.5)  # Make the table smaller
        table.to_edge(UP)  # Align the table to the top edge of the screen

        # Step 3: Animate the table
        self.play(Create(table))
        self.wait(2)

        # Step 4: Apply colors to all text entries
        for i, row in enumerate(data):
            group = row[1]  # "Mindfulness" or "Wandelaar"
            color = BLUE if group == "Wandelaar" else PINK
            for col_index in range(1, 4):  # Color all text elements in the row
                cell_text = table.get_entries((i + 1, col_index))  # Get the text in the cell
                self.play(cell_text.animate.set_color(color), run_time=0.1)

        self.wait(2)

        # Step 5: Reduce the table to show only the head and tail
        head_data = data[:5]  # First 5 rows (head)
        tail_data = data[-5:]  # Last 5 rows (tail)

        reduced_data = head_data + [["...", "...", "..."]] + tail_data
        reduced_table = Table(
            reduced_data,
            col_labels=[
                Text("Respondentnummer", font_size=20, color="#FFD700"),
                Text("Groep", font_size=20, color="#FFD700"),
                Text("Kwaliteit van Leven", font_size=20, color="#FFD700")
            ],
            include_outer_lines=True,
            line_config={"color": "#888888"}
        )

        # Apply colors to the reduced table's text
        for i, row in enumerate(reduced_data):
            if row[1] == "Mindfulness":
                color = PINK
            elif row[1] == "Wandelaar":
                color = BLUE
            else:
                continue  # Skip the "..." row
            for col_index in range(1, 4):
                cell_text = reduced_table.get_entries((i + 1, col_index))
                cell_text.set_color(color)

        reduced_table.scale(0.4)  # Smaller scale for the reduced table
        reduced_table.to_corner(UP + LEFT)  # Move to the top-left corner

        # Smooth transition from full table to reduced table
        self.play(Transform(table, reduced_table), run_time=2)
        self.wait(2)

